# How to change status background color with CoordinatorLayout and windowSoftInputMode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to use CoordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbar and SoftInputMode.When I tried to use android:fitsSystemWindows="false" in Coordinator Layout. It works well. But, SoftInputMode not working. That means when EditText is active the layout must resize. I added SOftInputMode to Manifest file.But ,It is not working.
[image]

The problem is when android:fitsSystemWindows="false", status bar background not working. But, Layout resizing working well.

Similarly, when android:fitsSystemWindows="true", status bar background works well. But, Layout resizing not working.

[image]

My code for Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:statusBarBackground="@color/myCustomColor"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeCorrdinate"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context="com.uiresource.messenger.Conversation">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_gradient_bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:expanded="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsetoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@drawable/my_gradient_bg"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleEnabled="false">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/realTabContent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0" />

                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/pager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"> 
                        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        style="@style/MyTabStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:showDividers="none"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
            </LinearLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/chipscrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                </RadioGroup>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/user1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Light"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h1" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart_fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:visibility="gone"

        app:layout_anchor="@id/htab_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/rl_bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_rvh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/chaty_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/hsv_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/chat_quick_area"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/rich_replies_card"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/editContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/hsv_content"
                android:background="#E9EDED"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space10"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/space5"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/space5"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space5">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bt_send"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_btnsend_rounded"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/space5"
                    android:src="@drawable/baseline_send_white_36"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Light"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/h3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bt_send"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/bt_attachment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:padding="@dimen/space10"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attachment" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_message"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt_attachment"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="Enter your message"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:padding="@dimen/space10"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/h2" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="bottom">


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.remove android:fitsSystemWindows="false",Because it can lead to layout scroll.on the Android 4.x
2.By setting style them to change the statusbar color.